# How to perform Power bi aggregate and filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with the following columns:

KO Datetime, Sistem, Health Sistem Value.Ko datetime can be null if Health is equal to 100

[image]

I would like to perform an aggragation so that I obtain the following table:

[image]

In the ouput table I am not interest in period of times where the health of the sytem is equal to 100%

Any hint on how to achieve it in power BI?

Comment: Check your question and add a better example of your data (produce some dummy data) and desired output.

Comment: @msta42a I have updated my question. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: It's not clear to me how the tables are related or why an aggregation has more rows and columns than the original.